# Better way to share HDD between KVM guests

Tags: kvm-virtualization, nfs, mdadm

Is there a better way to share HDD between multiply KVM guests at the same time then NFS? I have MDADM RAID 1 with all of my info and also I'm planning to take my Nextcloud to a KVM guest and want Nextcloud to be able to read/write all of my files on host RAID 1 and also at the same time other KVM guests need to be able to read/write the same RAID 1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: your question mix up with things, please clarify and be clear as possible what you want to solve

Answer (score 0):

You should try `9p_virtio`, which is a guest filesystem that can be used to access files on the host filesystem. Look at https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/9p_virtio for more information.